# Set different speed on Turtlebot wheels

Tags: python, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I set different speed for Turtlebot wheels using python? I've been using Twist() for making the Turtlebot move forward or rotate on one spot. How do I use angular and linear for setting speed on on wheels separately?
For instance, I want Turtlebot to go in a circle with a specific radius.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203153/set-different-speed-on-turtlebot-wheels/) by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot is not restricted to "one spot"; you can set both translational and rotational velocities in the same message.

With that said, although it's C++, see an answer I posted previously about the [relationship between linear and angular velocities](http://answers.ros.org/question/197626/cmd_vel-linear-and-angular-relationship/#197631) (and how to calculate them).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-02-23**:
Thank you, I will try doing that!